# Filter by field and select another field mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have used mongoose with my application and trying to retrieve the documents which has type as country and taking the metadata field of it.

my document looks as follows,

[image]

i have in code,

```
  dbHelper.query(mongoose.model('_entity'), {
                'type': 'country'
            }, function (error, data) {                
                callback(data);
            });
```

**dbHelper:**

```
query: function (model, conditon, options) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};
                model.find(conditon, {}, options, function (error, data) {
                    if (error)
                        console.log("error is"+err);
                        reject(error);
                    console.log("data is "+data);
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

how this should be changed in order to select the **`metadata`** field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `find` query a bit to select only the `metada` or whichever `fields` you want.

```
model.find(conditon, {"metadata" : 1}, options, function (error, data) {
    if (error)
        console.log("error is"+err);
        reject(error);
    console.log("data is "+data);
    resolve(data);
});
```

If you can't add metadata in the existing `find` query , you can try alternate method.

add another argument `projection` to the query function.

```
query: function (model, conditon, projection, options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        options = options || {};
        projection = projection || {};
        model.find(conditon, projection, options, function (error, data) {
            if (error)
                console.log("error is"+err);
                reject(error);
            console.log("data is "+data);
            resolve(data);
        })
    })
}
```

And use it like this:

```
dbHelper.query(mongoose.model('_entity'), {
    'type': 'country'
},{
    'metadata'  : 1//add other required fields if needed
}, function (error, data) {                
    callback(data);
});
```

I think this will work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You need `select`:

```
mongoose
  .model('_entity')
  .find()
  .where('type').equals('country')
  .select('metadata')
  .exec( function(error, data) {
      callback(data);
  });
```

Update:  for example `projection = ["metadata", "name"]`

```
query: function (model, conditon, projection, options) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};
                projection = projection || [];
                model.find(conditon, projection.join(" "), options, function (error, data) {
                    if (error)
                        console.log("error is"+err);
                        reject(error);
                    console.log("data is "+data);
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

Comment: i know we need to select, but how do i modify the above code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan What about `projection`?

Comment: how should i call this query now ?, conditions will be empty

Comment: projection.join is not a function